# Implementation independent way to see if a map contains null key

Tags: java, collections, null, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I have an API that receives a parameter which implements the `Map` interface. I need to check to see if this `Map` contains any `null` key. The problem is there are certain implementations of `Map`, such as `ConcurrentHashMap` which throw NPE if you call `contains(null)` on them.

What is a good, implementation independent way to see if an object that adheres to the `Map` interface contains a `null` key or not?

Note that I can't use `keySet` and check to see if that contains a null, because `ConcurrentHashMap` actually just wraps the `keySet` onto itself and ends up calling `contains` again underneath.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. I would rather not use `instanceOf` since that tends to look ugly when you have to corner case so many different types of `Map`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would do the trick:

```
private static Map<String, String> m = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean hasNullKey = false;
    try {
        if (m != null && m.containsKey(null)) {
            hasNullKey = true;
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
         // Relies on the fact that you can't add null keys to Map 
         // implementations that will throw when you check for one.
         // Add logging etc.
    }
    System.out.println("Does map have null key? " + hasNullKey);
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised there's no `Collection#isAllowNull()` or some such, but apparently there's not.  Yay for APIs that force you to use try/catch to test their capabilities and state.

Comment: I really hate catching an NPE like this. I'll wait a bit longer to see if there are better alternatives before I accept this.

Comment: @AbuZubair I agree, as Kevin says, a nice API method would be preferable but we're dealing with an interface here, so given no implementation specifics, nothing springs to mind. It would be nice if `ConcurrentHashMap` etc. looked for the null in `containsKey` and returned false.

Answer (score 0):

```
new HashSet<K>(map.keySet()).contains(null);
```

or if you don't want to copy all the keys:

```
boolean containsNull = false;
for (K k : map.keySet()) {
    if (k == null) {
        containsNull = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will certainly do the trick but has the overhead of  creating the new `HashSet`.

Comment: Yes I like this quite a bit but I can't take the perf hit of a new `HashSet`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp dependent upon the keyset implementation, you may now have an iteration overhead over my solution. If the keyset is a `HashSet` your implementation is O(n/2) rather than O(1).

Comment: I agree. I think all 3 solutions are ridiculous. The fact that you're forced to do any of these things is absurd. Why does `map.containsKey(null)` throw a NPE?!

Comment: @pbabcdefp seems like an oversight in the `ConcurrentHashMap` implementation. `containsKey` should return false for `null`.

Comment: It's quite a big oversight. The whole point of interfaces is that you're supposed to be able to use different implementations. For the record I would accept your answer if I were the OP. It avoids the iteration if the implementation doesn't allow `null`, and uses the quickest solution (`containsKey()`) if it does. You're not going to get any better than that.