# How to catch null pointer exception by the right way

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I implemented the method which should redirect to personal page if input data matched with data in database and user id is received successfully, but if it is null it has to redirect to the login page. How to handle null exception in this method? The loggedIn bolean is needed for the logined filter. Thank you for attention and help!

```
public String getLoginedUser() {
    UserDao ud = new UserDao();
    sessionBean.setCurrentUser(ud.getSessionUserFromDb(inputLogin, inputPassword));
    try {
        currentUserId = sessionBean.getCurrentUser().getUserId();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.print("Caught the NullPointerException");
    }

    if(currentUserId != 0){
    loggedIn = true;
    if(loggedIn = true){System.out.println("Logined successfully");}

            return sessionBean.redirectToPersonal();
       } 
            else {

         FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Login error!", "ERROR MSG");
    msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

    return sessionBean.redirectToLogin();
    }   
 }
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? *P.S*: You don't catch a `NPE`. Never.

Comment: @RohitJain There is one example when you should. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512362/implementation-independent-way-to-see-if-a-map-contains-null-key

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
if (sessionBean.getCurrentUser() != null) {
    currentUserId = sessionBean.getCurrentUser().getUserId()
} else {
    System.out.println("Current user is null!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check:

`if (sessionBean.getCurrentUser() == null)`

And then use your relevant code